# Terracotta 4.3 exception while initialization

Tags: spring, terracotta

I have downloaded trial version of terracotta 4.3 and am trying to configure my application that was earlier using terracotta 3.7 to use the new version. Have done the changes as suggested in the documentation [QuickSetupGuide](http://www.terracotta.org/generated/4.3.0/html/bmm-all/#page/BigMemory_Max_Documentation_Set/ta-ins_installing_bigmemory_max.html) but am getting the below error. Any suggestions or pointers to fix the issue would be higly appreciated. My application uses spring 3.2.1.

> ERROR 2015-07-20 18:03:03,276 (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader) - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pendingAccountCacheManager' defined in URL [file:/C:/dev/apache-tomcat-7.0.16_1/webapps/account/WEB-INF/classes/context/account-cacheloader.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Unable to load class net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.ExpressEnterpriseTerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory. Initial cause was org.terracotta.toolkit.ToolkitInstantiationException: toolkitUrl should be of form: 'toolkit:terracotta://server:tsa-port', invalid server:port specified - 'toolkit:terracotta://localhost:9510'
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>   Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Unable to load class net.sf.ehcache.terracotta.ExpressEnterpriseTerracottaClusteredInstanceFactory. Initial cause was org.terracotta.toolkit.ToolkitInstantiationException: toolkitUrl should be of form: 'toolkit:terracotta://server:tsa-port', invalid server:port specified - 'toolkit:terracotta://localhost:9510'

Kindly let me know if any more details are requred.

Comment: Well, it says invalid server:port provided....give your localmachines ip address and check on which port the software should run,.

Comment: Thanks @We are Borg for your comment. I got it resolved. But i am now getting a different error.                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/C:/dev/apache-tomcat-7.0.16_1/webapps/pendingaccount/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrs-api-3.0.9.Final.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class to jar:file:/C:/dev/apache-tomcat-7.0.16_1/webapps/pendingaccount/WEB-INF/lib/ehcache-ee-2.10.0.0.26.jar!/rest-management-private-classpath/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class_terracotta